# Batch Scripting - Finding OS Version information - Variable Output

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, version

I have a script that works perfectly.

```
 if not exist %SystemRoot%\system32\systeminfo.exe goto warnthenexit

 systeminfo | find "OS Name" > osname.txt

 FOR /F "usebackq delims=: tokens=2" %%i IN (osname.txt) DO set vers=%%i

 echo %vers% | find "Windows 7" > nul

 if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto VERSION_7
```

However, when I try to print the results like so:

```
Echo Current OS:%vers% - 64 Bit
```

It prints the results with a really! long gap. Like so:

```
Current OS:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise  - 64 Bit
```

Does anyone know why? or how I can remove the large gap?

Thanks a million!

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.TrimLeftFOR

Comment: Thanks, seems that changing the : to a %Space% after the Delims seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=: tokens=2" %%i IN (osname.txt) DO set vers=%%i
```

To

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=  tokens=2" %%i IN (osname.txt) DO set vers=%%i
```

*Changed the : to a %space% after delims...

Answer (score 1):

I know your script "works perfectly", but is not much efficient.

`SYSTEMINFO` takes a lot of time and `osname.txt` may be avoided.

Check:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,* DELIMS==" %%u IN ('WMIC OS GET CAPTION /VALUE') DO IF /I "%%u"=="Caption" SET vers=%%v
```

Comment: What is more, `systeminfo` output is localized, including "OS Name" label itself being replaced by translation (so `findstr "OS Name"` will not work in non-English Windows). `wmic`'s output, on the other hand, is not localized, so one can `findstr` all the way they want :-)